# Load scripts in html-file from same subdirectory (Apache)

Tags: javascript, html, apache, webserver

I feel like asking the most stupid question, but i searched for a while now and could not get it figured out.

I have the following file structure under my Apache DocumentRoot:

```
DocRoot
 - page1
   - ...
 - webapp
   - index.html
   - somescript.js
```

with index.html having a script tag looking like

```
<script src="somescript.js" type="text/javascript">
```

How do i configure Apache to serve https://myhostname.com/webapp so that the script get's loaded correctly? Page1 should stay accessible under https://myhostname/page1.

The current behaviour is that somescript.js does not get found, because the request is https://myhostname.com/somescript.js.

I do **NOT** want to set up a Virtual Host for this or edit the html file (get's generated).

Answer (score 0):

Are **webapp** and **page1** located in **var/www/html**? If so, probably your JS file is searched in html folder.

You have, at least, 2 solutions:

1. `<script src="/webapp/somescript.js" type="text/javascript">`
2. Configure virtual hosts for webapp and page1. So, you'll be able to connect to that pages via **webapp.myhostname.com** and **page1.myhostname.com** subdomens, and `<script src="somescript.js" type="text/javascript">` will work for both of them, searching in their folders

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I should have mentioned that option 1 is not good for my case (updated now).
Option 2 does not satisfy the need to serve the pages under the given URLs.

Comment: Then you may get current folder name, and on generation add the folder name

Comment: No, development must stay separated from deployment. This is something that the web-server must be able to do.

Comment: Virtual host is what you need. Or you may invent your own web server